# Is there a tag to require real life travel experience?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Quit some (good) answer are given based on smart search. Sometimes you need a been there, seen it, done it kind of answer. Would it be an idea to make a specific tag to require an answer from some one who really have som real experience?

Comment: Interesting idea. Problem is most new users requiring this aren't going to be clearly looking for such a tag, perhaps? Has made me think tho :)

Comment: This is what the text of your question and voting is for. Repurposing tags for this sort of thing breaks tags altogether.

Comment: We have a somewhat similar tag, [tag:local-knowledge].

Comment: @hippietrail that tag looks pretty heavily misused/overused to me...

Comment: Hmm I would agree that it's also probably a meta tag and also maybe not a great tag, but with a grand total of two uses I can't agree that it's currently "overused" (-:

Comment: @hippietrail I count 6 uses. Of them, only one or two are borderline appropriate. Perhaps substitute "misused" for "overused". Honestly, we should probably just nuke the tag.

Answer (score 10):

This would be a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and a bad one for all the reasons meta tags are bad in general.

It's subjective. Do I really need to have been there? Isn't it enough to have heard from someone who was there? What if I saw it from a distance? I was asleep and my wife did all the driving and talking?

For the same reasons, it doesn't help guide answerers towards the questions they can answer.

It doesn't work as the sole tag of a question, only in a supplemental fashion.

And the nail in the coffin: it does nothing whatsoever to help people find the question they're after.

Comment: I am genuinely puzzled by the meaning of the word “subjective” in this answer. Obviously, it's a requirement set by the person asking the question but it can't possibly be a useful definition of “subjective” here as *any* question is subjective in that sense.

Comment: Consider this: If I am asking about going somewhere by public transport, you could just as well ask “Do you really need to travel by public transport?”, “Would any sort of overland travel count?”, “Are you interested in hitchhiking?”, etc. Anybody asking about that *could* in some sense travel with a private jet, an helicopter, whatever, it's just not what they are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a tag to require real life travel experience?

No, nor should there be, as explained by @Gilles and to some extent covered by [Is asking for personal experience on topic (and if not, under what category is it excluded)?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3900/is-asking-for-personal-experience-on-topic-and-if-not-under-what-category-is-i).